# How can I open a .json.gz format file in R?

Tags: r, json, gzip

I am a Data Science student writing my thesis using product review data. However, this is packed in a .gz file.

The file name when downloaded is 'xxx.json.gz' and when I look into the properties it says the type of file is gz Archive (.gz), Opens with 7-Zip File Manager.

I found the following code:

```
z <- gzfile("xxx.json.gz")
data = read.csv(z)
```

But the object 'data' is now a list. All columns are factors and the column with the review text is not right at all. I think the read.csv() part is wrong since it's supposed to be a json file.

Does anyone have solution? I also have the URL address of the data if that's better to use: http://deepyeti.ucsd.edu/jianmo/amazon/categoryFilesSmall/Electronics_5.json.gz

Comment: If you can share the URL that would be great

Comment: Here it is! @NotThatKindODr http://deepyeti.ucsd.edu/jianmo/amazon/categoryFilesSmall/Electronics_5.json.gz

Answer (score 2):

Loading it at the moment, I got 5,152,500 records right now, it is probably the review text that is clogging it up

```
library(jsonlite)
happy_data <-stream_in(
gzcon(
   url("http://deepyeti.ucsd.edu/jianmo/amazon/categoryFilesSmall/Electronics_5.json.gz")
 )
                       )
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried running it but I get a silly error... Error: unexpected '/' in "happy_data <- stream_in(gzcon(url(http:/"

Comment: I am going to try to find another solution, this one crashed my session, it was too big to use stream_in

Comment: I forgot the " " around the URL sorry

Comment: Thanks, I saw it right after my comment. I've been looking for solutions without any luck.

Comment: Mine stopped too and gave this warning:

Found 5227500 records...Error: parse error: premature EOF
                                       {"overall": 5.0, "verified": tr
                     (right here) ------^
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(con, n = pagesize, encoding = "UTF-8") :
  incomplete final line found on 'gzcon(http://deepyeti.ucsd.edu/jianmo/amazon/categoryFilesSmall/Electronics_5.json.gz)'
closing gzcon input connection.